# iOS8 (Custom Keyboard) how make background transparent?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

I'm working on custom keyboard for iOS 8. By default it has grey background color.

If you are setting some color for its view background - all is OK, but how can I make it transparent? (`UIColor.clearColor()` doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a xib file to load the view ? 
Or did you do everything programmatically ?

I did mine using a xib file, I set the background color in the story to the default empty one.
Then before viewDidLoad I set it up to clearcolor, qnd it works. I got the same background than the default keyboard.

Comment: But i whant to set cleer color, so i can see the application below in keyboard background.

Comment: I don't think you can do something 100% transparent.
I think the best you can do is the same as the default keyboard : a translucent background.
Also note that the background turns opaque grey when the background of the app is white (default iOS keyboard also behave like that).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with a keyboard, but can you set a background PNG? If so, create a 1px by 1px PNG that's clear (keep the transparency in your PNG). Use that as your background image.  It appears there is currently a bug in the SDK that is causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately you can't display the keyboard's background as `.clear` (transparent)** but you can change it to other colors. More on that:

Remember when using a nib, there are 2 views - the nib's view and the `ViewController`'s view. You can change the nib's background to `.clear`, but that just show's the `ViewController`'s view (in this case, `KeyboardViewController`)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
    let keyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil) [0] as? UIView
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    keyboardView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Where the above really comes in handy is when you want the nib's view to match the `ViewController`'s view (`keyboardView.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor` also does the same).

If you're just wanting to change the nib's color, you can just set the nib's background color to whatever color you want since its in front of the `keyboardViewController`'s view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
    let keyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil) [0] as? UIView
    keyboardView.backgroundColor = .red
}
```